# Having trouble with my autoclicker not executing the right cps

Tags: c++

I'm a pretty new and naïve dev (so sorry if this is a dumb question) and I was making an auto clicker for a quick exercise with c++ but when I tested my program, it was clicking either too fast or too slow most of the time. For example, if I entered a cps of 50 into my program, it would only be able to output 31 cps and if I entered a cps of 20, it would only output 15 cps etc.

Here is some of the code that runs what I am talking about:

```
double cps;
cout << "Please enter the desired cps: " << endl;
cin >> cps;
long double delay = (1000.0 / cps);
cout << "Hold ctrl to click!." << endl;
cout << delay << endl;
while (true) {
    while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)) {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

These irregularities showed no discernible pattern or cause for all I know so I am at a loss for answers here. Help would be much appreciated as I am losing my mind because of this. Thanks!

Comment: `Sleep(delay)` takes some amount of time (`delay`+ overhead). `mouse_event` and `GetAsyncKeyState` can also take some time. What happens when you account for the time these take when calculating the desired delay?

Comment: That's a good point. Ill look into that now.